# How to take dict values from list using django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

My views:

```
post_details = Post.objects.all()
    for each in post_details:
        post_like_list=PostLikes.objects.filter(post = each)
        pl=len(post_like_list)
        dict1={"post":each}
        dict2={"how many likes":pl}
        list.append([dict1,dict2])
    print list
```

My list =[[{'post': Accommodation}, {'how many likes': 0}], [{'post': Election}, {'how many likes': 0}], [{'post': }, {'how many likes': 3}], [{'post': }, {'how many likes': 1}]]

By using django templates , how can i get 'post' and 'how many likes' from dictionary in list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the structure sane...

```
    list.append({"post": each, "how many likes": pl})
```

then you'll find that you can use `{% for %}` to iterate over the list, then access the dicts using normal access methods.